# What is meant by "contiguous alternative hypothesis"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, random-variable

I am reading a paper on Chimeric Alternatives which introduces what it calls contiguous alternatives. Namely, we have a sequence of random variables $[X_i]_1^n$ which follow some distribution $f$ under the null hypothesis, and we wish to test this against a "class of contiguous alternatives" where the distribution of each $X_i$ is some $\tilde{f}=\tilde{f}_n$ which depends on $n$.

I can't find a meaningful definition of "contiguous alternative" online. The only relevant information I found is [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguity_(probability_theory)) which states two probability measures are contiguous if they share the same support.

So if I had to guess, a class of contiguous alternatives is one in which the alternative distributions all share the same support?